# What sort of key should this be?

Tags: database, key

This may be a really simple problem to some people, but I'm finding it hard to understand.

The scenario:
I'm working with a school database.
I have a table which relates a class to a subject called 'subject_class'.

A class can be a part of more than one subject, and a subject can can contain more than one class. So from what I understand, this is a many-to-many relation within a table.

An example of how the database would look:

```
subject_id          class_id
    1                 14
    1                 15
    2                 14
    *1                *14
```

As you can see, the same data can be entered into the table more than once (shown above with an asterisk). I want this to stop happening. My question is, what sort of key would this be? and why? or how could I stop the problem from happening?

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't, and I will provide more info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of database is this? MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to have a unique key on subject_id and class_id to prevent duplicates.  But you NEED to make sure your application can either: handle the error thrown when you try to insert a value combination that is already there and make try to prevent it from submitting duplicates in the first place.

Alternatively, if you want the subsequent insert to overwrite the existing entry, you should look into whether your database software can handle ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all you need is one [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html) applied to both columns. The general flow is as follows: the application tries to save the relation without validating in prior to the action and awaits the database answer. In case of duplication the insert returns an error, which should be handled further in the app.

Comment: He wants it so that each column can have multiple entries, as long as no two rows of both columns are the same.  So having (subject,class) of (1,2) (1,3) (2,4) is OK, but having (1,2) twice is not.

Comment: @Tim and thats exactly why there is *one* unique key applied to two columns.

Comment: Sorry, misread.  Thought you meant each column should be a unique.

Answer (score 0):

You want a unique key, spanning both rows: This way both columns **each** can have non-unique data, but not in **combination**

```
ALTER TABLE subject_class ADD UNIQUE INDEX sanity (subject_id, class_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better if you validate it at your application programming language you are using. Apply check for such before you update insert in to database.

At database level you can use composite unique key.To uniqually identify a row.

```
alter table subject_class ADD UNIQUE INDEX sanity (subject_id, class_id);
```

Comment: That does not handle synchronous request as well, at least not as easily by all means.

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key across the two fields

```
ALTER TABLE subject_class ADD PRIMARY KEY (subject_id, class_id)
```

but you will need to remove the duplicates before you can add the index.

Answer (score -1):

Add a UNIQUE on both fields.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE (  `subject_id` ,  `class_id` ) ;
```